# SharePoint PnP Provisioning with Azure on SharePoint Subsite

Tags: azure, powershell, sharepoint, provisioning, sitetemplate

Hope you guys are doing best, Actually I have issue on implementing Root Site template on Subsites of SharePoint with Azure using PnP PowerShell Script. After lot of search on web I tried to implement with Azure storage account and with Azure functions. I have also change "Scope='Web'" in template.xml file but template is not applying anymore, also there is no error but function runs successfully. I am providing Code here please have a look and help me. Thanks in advance.

**With Azure Automation**

Connect-PnPOnline -ClientId "**********" -ClientSecret "***********" -Url "https://Contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/TargetComSite/agreement_47"
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out template.pnp -IncludeAllClientSidePages -PersistBrandingFiles

Connect-PnPOnline -ClientId "**********" -ClientSecret "***********" -Url "https://Contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/TargetComSite/agreement_49"
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path .\template.pnp

**With Azure Function**

param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

#$requestBody = Get-Content $Request -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

$path = "C:\home"
$env:PSModulePath += ";$path\Modules\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline"
Write-Output "Running PnP version:"
(Get-Module -Name SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -ListAvailable).Version

Connect-PnPOnline -AppId "#####" -AppSecret "***************" -Url https://Contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/TargetComSite/agreement_49

Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path C:\home\site\wwwroot\ApplyPnPProvisioningTemplate\template.xml -ClearNavigation

Comment: Can you provide us the screenshot of error you're getting?

Comment: Hi @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT actually no error comes, functions runs successfully but template not applied

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and the solution was simply to wait. Sometimes the changes are not applied directly and it takes some time (hours in some cases) to be applied